# Oracle NVL returning inconsistence result when used with/without CASE statement

Tags: php, oracle, case, oracle18c, nvl

Can anybody help me to understand why oracle db is returning inconsistence result when used with/without CASE statement.

```
SELECT NVL(CASE WHEN '' IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE NULL END ,TO_DATE('19010101', 'YYYYMMDD')) a,
   NVL(CASE WHEN '' IS NOT NULL THEN NULL ELSE NULL END ,TO_DATE('19010101', 'YYYYMMDD')) b,
   NVL(CASE WHEN '' = '' THEN NULL ELSE NULL END ,TO_DATE('19010101', 'YYYYMMDD')) c,
   NVL(NULL ,TO_DATE('19010101', 'YYYYMMDD')) d from dual;
```

[image: run results]

My actual query uses `TRUNC(NVL(:NEW_FORM_TIME_END, TO_DATE('19010101', 'YYYYMMDD'))) >= TRUNC(SYSDATE - INTERVAL '2' DAY)` where `NEW_FORM_TIME_END` could be empty string or NULL but I'm getting this error `ORA-06550: line 240, column 91: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to '>=' ORA-06550: line 229, column 9: PL/SQL: Statement ignored`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your case expressions are of type `VARCHAR2` which is the default type if you're not providing explicit types. A `NULL` literal doesn't have a type. `NVL(<varchar2>, <date>)` applies an implicit type conversion on the `<date>` argument. In other RDBMS, you'd simply get an error because of incompatible types. The PL/SQL version of your expression probably also suffers from a similar problem, although not exactly the same one as you're presenting in your query.

Just make sure you always compare the same types.

Try this to check:

```sql
SELECT 
  NVL(CAST(CASE WHEN '' IS NULL THEN NULL END AS DATE), DATE '1901-01-01') a,
  NVL(CAST(CASE WHEN '' IS NOT NULL THEN NULL END AS DATE), DATE '1901-01-01') b,
  NVL(CAST(CASE WHEN '' = '' THEN NULL END AS DATE), DATE '1901-01-01') c,
  NVL(NULL, DATE '1901-01-01') d
FROM dual;
```

Or alternatively, create a view from your table and then check the dictionary:

```sql
CREATE VIEW v AS
SELECT 
  NVL(CASE WHEN '' IS NULL THEN NULL END, DATE '1901-01-01') a,
  NVL(CASE WHEN '' IS NOT NULL THEN NULL END, DATE '1901-01-01') b,
  NVL(CASE WHEN '' = '' THEN NULL END, DATE '1901-01-01') c,
  NVL(NULL, TO_DATE('19010101', 'YYYYMMDD')) d
FROM dual;

SELECT column_name, data_type
FROM all_tab_cols
WHERE table_name = 'V'
ORDER BY column_name;
```

Yielding

```
|COLUMN_NAME|DATA_TYPE|
|-----------|---------|
|A          |VARCHAR2 |
|B          |VARCHAR2 |
|C          |VARCHAR2 |
|D          |DATE     |
```

Comment: Thanks:) I Didn't know about the implicit type conversion

Answer (score 0):

Let's analyze all of them:

```
NVL(CASE WHEN '' IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE NULL END ,TO_DATE('19010101', 'YYYYMMDD'))
```

This should return `TO_DATE('19010101', 'YYYYMMDD'))` since `''` is the same as `NULL` in Oracle and the `THEN NULL` branch is returned.

```
NVL(CASE WHEN '' IS NOT NULL THEN NULL ELSE NULL END ,TO_DATE('19010101', 'YYYYMMDD'))
```

This one should also return `TO_DATE('19010101', 'YYYYMMDD')) since` '' IS NOT NULL`is`false `and the`ELSE NULL` branch is returned.

```
NVL(CASE WHEN '' = '' THEN NULL ELSE NULL END ,TO_DATE('19010101', 'YYYYMMDD'))
```

In Oracle, `'' = ''` translates to `NULL = NULL`, which in SQL, evaluates to `NULL`, so `TO_DATE('19010101', 'YYYYMMDD')) is returned.

```
NVL(NULL ,TO_DATE('19010101', 'YYYYMMDD'))
```

This one should also return `TO_DATE('19010101', 'YYYYMMDD'))`